# Are ubuntu 20.10 packages compatible with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, 20.10, downgrade, apt-cache

I have installed Ubuntu 20.10, since it is non LTS, I'd like to have 20.04.
Problem is I have already installed lots of apt packages in my 20.10. So is it possible to reuse the apt cache in my newly installed 20.04? I really don't wanna download them all again as I have a limited internet connection.

Comment: No, most are not.   The odd package has no conflicts, for example wallpaper packages have no dependencies that will create issues with other systems, but most packages contain more complex things inside than just wallpapers.  Examples of a package would allow a better example, but generally no.

Answer (score 1):

No, most are not re-usable in other release.

The odd package has no conflicts, for example wallpaper packages have no dependencies that will create issues with other systems, but most packages contain more complex things inside than just wallpapers.

If you look at the requirements of `gnome-shell`

https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy-updates/gnome-shell

compared with

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/gnome-shell

You'll note many rules are the same, but that doesn't apply to all. You've have to check all rules for all dependencies... which is why wallpaper package examples are easy (*they have minimal to no dependencies usually, eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/ubuntu-wallpapers*).